# Looking for a better formula in Excel to Calculate Duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have  621224 * 1 data in my Excel Sheet and have to calculate total no. of duplicates in the sheet but it takes a lot too much time with `=IF(COUNTIF($J$1000:J14353,J5353)>1,1,0)` so this formula might be taking n^2 complexity to find duplicates, I am looking for a formula that takes less time and if possible takes nlogn time, if there is in Excel

As of now I am doing this task manually taking a range of 10k which works in acceptable time and also to add on I have sorted the list
I searched for vlookup and found it will take around same time as countif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've **sorted** the data then you can use *binary* searching, which will be many times faster than your current *linear* set-up with `COUNTIFS`. For example:

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(MATCH(A1:A750000,A:A)<>ROW(A1:A750000)))`

On my machine, this produced a result in less than 1 second.

If you aren't able to first sort the data, if you have `Office 365` you can perform the sorting *in-formula*:

`=LET(ζ,A1:A750000,ξ,SORT(ζ),SUMPRODUCT(N(MATCH(ξ,ξ)<>SEQUENCE(ROWS(ζ)))))`

which should still be very fast.

Comment: Since the data is sorted maybe you can use `XMATCH` Instead and call it with the input argument `[search_mode]` and set it to `2` to ensure a binary search.  I haven’t test it, but it could be a possible improvement to your approach.

Comment: @DavidLeal If you don't specify a *match_type* parameter for `MATCH` it defaults to 1, which is for binary searching, so it will be no different to your suggested use of `XMATCH`.

Comment: Thanks `XMATCH` has both input arguments: `search_mode` and `match_type` and `MATCH` only the last one. Microsoft doesn’t provide too much documentation. For search mode `2` it explicitly states binary search. But may be as you say there is no difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Xmatch's default is to sort even if you don't tell it to. I will try and post something later to demonstrate.

Comment: I tested it with `XMATCH` the following: `=LET(x, {1;2;2;3;3;3}, dupCnt,LAMBDA(y,SUMPRODUCT(N(XMATCH(y,y)<>SEQUENCE(ROWS(y))))),HSTACK(dupCnt(x), dupCnt(SORT(x,,-1)))
)` in both cases returns the same result, even changing randomly the order. So *it seems `XMATCH` does implicitly a sort*. Maybe for a large dataset `MATCH` (but it has to be sorted first) has a better performance than `XMATCH` but I don't know something to be tested.

Comment: I tried to mark the duplicates as 1 and other values as 0 with this formula `=IFERROR(N(MATCH(J77681,J77682:J$621224)),0)`  and this also looks slow (not executing) but `=SUMPRODUCT(N(MATCH(A1:A750000,A:A)<>ROW(A1:A750000)))` this works just fine in 1 second what is the reason behind is it the time to output that it takes

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring `IF()` may faster. Try-

```
=SUM(--(COUNTIFS(A3:A13,A3:A13)>1))
```

[image]